# Paperclip won't display/detect file size of anything that is not an image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I'm working on an app that allows users to upload videos, pictures, audio clips, and documents. The files are being uploaded with the Paperclip gem and being stored on s3.

Right now I am running some processing on the file sizes after they are uploaded, but paperclip continues to save the file to the database with a file size of `'0'` on any file that is not `.jpg, .gif, .png`. I've tried inspecting the file size myself, the upload's length, and several other hair brained ideas.

Is there anyway to monkeypatch, or hijack the request from paperclip to find out what the file size is? Has anyone run into this issue before?

Answer (score 1):

By default, Paperclip is built to process images. If you need to be able to handle other file types, you'll have to look into writing your own Processor: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/processor.rb. This will allow you to process files in whatever way you need when declared in your model:

```
has_attached_file :scan, :styles => { :text => { :quality => :better } },
                  :processors => [:ocr]
```

Here's an important point from the README docs:

> NOTE: Because processors operate by turning the original attachment
>   into the styles, no processors will be run if there are no styles
>   defined.

This means you'll need to specify some sort of `styles` in order for your processor or any other processor to get run. For a basic custom processor something as simple as `:styles => { :default => true }` should be enough to get you going.

Comment: Thanks @andrewle  This is immensely helpful. I'll have to work on my own processor then. All I really need is the source File's size though, I wonder how much work that will take. 
I'll start by adding the styles as you suggested and see what becomes of it. Thanks again.